# How to create a sigfile of extension .SF/.DSA & use it with androiddeployqt command?

Tags: android, qt, app-store, code-signing, jarsigner

I have Qt application to deploy on Android. I am using command line build to generate an apk signed with my `.keystore` file. I am well able to do it using following command where I am using `androiddeployqt`.

`androiddeployqt --sign my_key.keystore myAlias --storepass my_password --output android --verbose --input my_app.so-deployment-settings.json`

Above command works great from my shell script to generate a signed apk. But I want to avoid writing my password on the command as done above. Typing `androiddeployqt -help` shows that there is a `--sigfile <file>: Name of .SF/.DSA file` option that I can use. But I don't know how to create this sigfile of extension .SF/.DSA.

Can someone please suggest how to create a `sigfile of extension .SF/.DSA` which I can use with `androiddeployqt command with --sigfile` as option ? Am I correct in understanding that I need a file of extension .SF or .DSA ?

Or, is there some other way I can hide my password from showing up on the script's code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I had to look at the oracle docs..as long as you have a keystore cert you supply the sigfile names it it creates those files for you per:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signing.html

and the qt tool you are using plugins into that so you should be good to go